# How to display multiple notifications with Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a Vue 3 app using Vuetify. Inside a component I'm listening to streamed events. For each new event I want to display a notification fading out after x seconds. I think the [Snackbar](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/snackbars/) component is the correct one to pick but unfortunately a snackbar list isn't supported ( [maybe in the near future](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/2384) )

I started with a `NotificationList` component expecting notifications as a prop and tries to display them in a stacked list

[Reproduction link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

```
<template>
  <v-snackbar 
              v-for="[notificationId, notificationMessage] in notifications"
              :ref="snackbarElement => notificationReferences.set(notificationId, snackbarElement)"
              :key="notificationId" 
              :model-value="true"
              location="top right"
              @update:model-value="emit('removeNotification', notificationId)"
  >
    {{ notificationMessage }}
  </v-snackbar>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, watch, watchEffect } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps<{ notifications: Map<string, string> }>();

const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: 'removeNotification', id: string): void
}>()

const notificationReferences = ref(new Map<string, unknown>());

watch(props.notifications, () => {
  // clear all references to avoid dead ones
  // notificationReferences.value.clear();
}, { immediate: true });

watchEffect(() => {
  let notificationIndex = 0;
  
  for (const [notificationId, snackbarElement] of notificationReferences.value) {
    // const snackbarElementHeight = ??? // get height from Vuetify component
    const marginTop = notificationIndex * 60; // snackbarElementHeight;
    
    // snackbarElement.style.marginTop = marginTop + "px";
    // snackbarElement.style.setProperty('margin-top', marginTop + "px");
    
    notificationIndex++;
  }
});
</script>
```

So other components, e.g. the `App` component can consume it like so

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-btn @click="addNotification">New notification</v-btn>
      <notification-list :notifications="notifications" @removeNotification="removeNotification" />
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import NotificationList from './NotificationList.vue'

const notifications = ref<Map<string, string>>(new Map())

function addNotification() {
  const notificationId = self.crypto.randomUUID();
  const notificationMessage = (new Date()).toString();
  
  notifications.value.set(notificationId, notificationMessage);
}

function removeNotification(notificationId) {
  notifications.value.delete(notificationId);
}
</script>
```

I think the code is almost fine, the only thing missing is the vertical offset, currently all snackbars have the same position.

The problem is that when I try to apply a margin to `snackbarElement` I get the error

> TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'marginTop')

but when I try to debug it, e.g. logging the variable, I get the error

> TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value

I think this is related to Vuetify because I can't  reproduce it with Vue and plain div elements, [sample](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqdU02PmzAQ/SsjLku0iemZEtRKu4dI3apqtaeyBxYG4g3Ylm2SriL+e8d2Ekja0x4ibM+bj/fm5Rh9VYrtB4zSKLPYq660mBcCIHsdrJUCvlQdr3brIirrekOIIsq/4wE4HbMkYALevaw6biyk7mgoxX+LCBJCZMmsPF1NpbmyYNAOCrpStIS3BKYo75XUFo6gsYERGi17uKMZ7y4hN8g31yrEWHJ+cFQIVohKCgr7AWDtCmVPpcqM1Vy0SwjfPI8FUaFAvFi4pGYQleVE+sQ1XsDRcZuKbWqqZrBrWKXflZVMl6KW/fPz5iFefL7GPqExZYuU4Ns8EHXqw6z85buf8O7nx2T7shuQkSBx6LScV3Hg0akYdMujZRS0WPWlYm9GCtqgH5Zk9wHSMg3juzfSxd2LaGutMmmSmKZyYr0ZJnWb0InpQVjeI0PTr161PBjUVLiIXAlqPVLLucz/Oqbme9ivGqlplb//w+EFuAhcyRMp7YRwlPPYYY/Cwjr3wZ/YoEZRobnSYgIuXPYO308G29TeNI7m8Xgl/EhT01gJpX7cgEs4lLbaPjYNVvbGjWebKS2Vs1mNDRf4w92yMIpJnb1ufQdj7rc/t+lEO/j1bM1L7iB2Qh4EZYbU2VgxGZXU88vu8ORUUeMfKvXp4jJaDMSh4WU7k6ovIJtb/b0jT/+B4GzZIetkG8+24euHDgBJQrAaoZXEY0t1GGPz+GWy+3uf53zlKky+Hv8ClCOSwg==)

Do you have any ideas how to fix this? Maybe my approach can be simplified?

---

**Sidenote:**

I found https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-snackbar/#props-offset so maybe I don't even have to deal with `notificationReferences` at all but the `offset` prop had no impact, [sample](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqVUMtuAiEU/RXCWkBjF83ENvYbuhQXOHN1qLwCzDSN8d8LOE7t2DbpjnPu5Tzu5oRfnKN9B7jCqwjaKRHhmRuEVj0RzpVnAVpIM6CCgxH1cSc8qrRtQJFeqA6eOI6+A46RsrWI0prMWIe8PLQx0VFqsF1MLFkkWNn9PkCGi/mc41EfodfWdqpBregBXZZGb/Zlfo2XqDFfBpfkKzY2wjMstbM+pj1H34I1qfApr/NhEDiuUGEyly6SMcdtjC5UjHXGHQ+0tpqt04z5zuQqpLF6vaRLOidCuVbQB9bIEG/HFIImO2/fA/hkzPHsxiPK/cdvPsM4yS/o40V2oIgSu5B17/RYMunBEw+mAQ/+zw6T3Z96TFbuumTrMzfndF4lzTFMLluHctXNNeH/SxaF/H2bXc4z/C1ksi0f8fYTCX7qKA==)

---

**"Bad" temporary workaround**

I could add a computed property calculating a margin for each snackbar, *assuming a margin of 60px is enough*, so that solution is pretty simple but **won't work** for different snackbar heights

[Solution](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: You will have to add this functionality yourself.  Fortunately, you are not the first person to want this feature and you can find tutorials like [this one](https://github.com/Aymkdn/v-snackbars) showing how you can add it.  The tutorial is specifically for Vuetify 2 but I don't believe there's any reason why it won't work the same with Vuetify 3.

Comment: The best library I have ever used for notifications is vue-toastification(https://github.com/Maronato/vue-toastification). It is available for Vue3. You can see the demo here(https://vue-toastification.maronato.dev/) and use this instead of manual work in the snack bar.

Comment: What if you set a max-height for your snackbar? Then you can set the margin with peace of mind. And you should set the margin to zero after a certain number of adding margins (not to over pass the good height of the page)

Comment: @EspressoCode yes, I thought about that. But I think my problem is not related to snackbars anymore... I mean the code is almost fine, only the `snackbarElement` variable inside `watchEffect` is struggling...

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you will not get a canonical answer,
as for [Material Design specifications](https://m2.material.io/components/snackbars#behavior):

> When multiple snackbar updates are necessary, they should appear one
> at a time.
>
> […] Avoid stacking snackbars on top of one another.

If you want to do it anyways, I would recommend to use [v-alert](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/alerts/) components. You will need a bit of styling, a transition and a timeout to get what you want. Not the perfect solution but, in my opinion, way less hackish than trying to do something similar using snackbars.

```html
<div class="notificationContainer">
  <v-slide-y-transition group>
    <v-alert
      v-for="notification in notifications"
      theme="dark"
    >{{ notification[1] }}</v-alert>
  </v-slide-y-transition>
</div>
<v-btn @click="addNotification">New notification</v-btn>
```

```css
.notificationContainer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: .5em;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

[Here](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) you can see a working example.

Comment: thanks for your approach. As already mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75616980/how-to-display-multiple-notifications-with-vuetify/75750575#comment133599233_75616980 I think I almost got it... I'm just wondering why the references are broken

Answer (score 0):

use filter method instead of splice

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: I updated my question :) I found a better solution but I'm struggling with the last part